# Validación de un formulario con Bootstrap modal

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, bootstrap, modal

tengo un problema el cual consta de lo siguiente, tengo un formulario dentro de una ventana modal y tengo que validar que los campos no estén vacíos, para ese modo utilice valídate de JavaScript el cual me valida, lo que pasa es que el formulario cuando ya esta validado que esta vacío, yo cierro la modal y la vuelvo a abrir aparece aun con los campos rojos que no hay ningún campo lleno aun así teniendo los campos completos.

Lo que necesito es algo así como que se al darle clic al botón salga la modal como nueva pero tampoco que me borre los datos de la modal de actualizar

este es el botón.

`<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>`

esta es la modal.

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true"><img src="{{ url('fotos/close.png') }}" alt="close" width="20"
                            height="20"></span>
                </button>
                <h2 class="modal-title">Actualizar Torre</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="miFormEdit" method="post" action="{{route('torres.update', 'test')}}" data-toggle="validator"
                    class="form-horizontal">
                    @method('patch')
                    @csrf
                    <input type="hidden" name="TorreId" id="tor_id" value="">

                    <div class="item form-group">
                        <label for="nombre" class="control-label col-md-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3"
                            data-toggle="validator">Nombre
                            <span>*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombreedit" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"
                                placeholder="Ingresa el nombre de la torre" required
                                pattern="[A-Za-z0-9 _-]{1,15}"></input>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @include('torres.form')

                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            $('#edit').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                                $('#nombreedit').trigger('focus');
                            });
                        });

                    </script>

                    <div class="form-group" align="center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Actualizar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal"
                        >Cancelar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>´
```

Anexo pantallazo

Para la vista del usuario se vería feo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo lo que suelo hacer con los modals, es tener uno hecho en la plantilla base y cuando necesito usar un modal en cualquier lado, hago que con ajax me cargue el contenido.

Answer (score 0):

Sebastián.

Lo que necesitas es limpiar la validación que metiste con JS al cerrar el modal, no sé si lo hayas realizado de forma manual, o en su defecto, usado una librería que te ayude con esto.

Esto se logra a través de la siguiente función, la cual es un evento al momento de que se cierra el modal:

```
    $('#tuModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {

          //Reversas la validación

});
```

Comment: Hola @Luis como así?  que podría colocar en "reversas la validación", yo las validaciones las estoy haciendo con validator.js

Comment: Hola, @SebastianMuñoz, disculpa la demora, ¿Puedes pasarme el link del validador? Con lo de la revsersa, me refiero a que usualmente, en la documentación debe incluir un método para eliminar la validación. Por ejemplo yo uso Parsleyjs, y para quitar la validación, solo uso .parsley.reset()

Comment: Hola @Luis disculpa también haberme demorado, este es el validador que utilice https://github.com/yairEO/validator, pero le han cambiado cosas yo utilice la versión 1.1.0

Comment: Perdon @Luis el q utilice fue este https://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/